# Why inclustered index scan on a table has number of execution as 8?

Tags: sql-server

The query I am running against a table in sql server appears to have 8 as the actual number of execution for the inclusted index scan operator. Why is that as I understand scan should only take place once? Also the clustered index column is a uniqueidentifider column, which appears to be very slow given the total number of records in the table is only just over 300,000 rows.

Many thanks.

Best regards,

Comment: I assume you're referring to "non-clustered" index, right? It would be more helpful if you shared the execution plan with us. You can use [pasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and update your question and add the link to the shared execution plan.

Comment: show the execution plan. Probably either on the inside of a nested loops or parallel plan with DOP of 8

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it turned out it was using parallelism. So it makes sense each thread is doing a single scan.

Comment: A uniqueidentifier as a clustered index is indeed a bad idea for performance. The index fragmentation will reach 99.99% with as few as a couple thousand rows. Choosing another column as a clustered index would be a better idea. Or you will constantly have to defragment that index. This has been documented by countless people. But here is one of the best articles in my opinion on this topic. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/